# Присвоение результата команды переменной BASH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

```
#!/bin/bash
ls $1/*[0-9]*.txt | sort > new.txt
WC -l < new.txt
n=$(wc -l < new.txt)
echo $n
echo work finished
```

Есть следующий код, который должен записывать в алфавитном порядке в файл new.txt результат поиска по шаблону в заданной папке. После нужно подсчитать количество строк и присвоить их переменной `n`.

Проблема в том, что команда работает и выводит результат, однако при попытке присвоить результат переменной, выдаёт ошибку, что такого файла не существует.

В чём ошибка?

Comment: наверно WC -> wc

Comment: Это автозамена поработала, команда с капсом работает, присвоение - нет -.- Но спасибо.

Comment: тогда приведите ошибку вместе с тем - как запускается. и в каком шеле запускается код. потому что в bash - этот код работает без проблем. как вариант  - укажи полный путь к wc и echo

Comment: Если «команда с капсом работает», то как раз наоборот — `wc` —> `WC`.